# Conditional LINQ where statement?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have a linq statement that I want to add an additional where clause to if a drop down index is not 0.

```
people.Where(n.surname == "surname" || n.forename == "forename" && (dropdown.SelectedIndex > 0) ? n.id = dropdown.SelectedValue : n.id  > 0).Select(n => n);
```

I am not even sure if what I am trying is possible??

I would like to do this rather than having to write two different statements.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fortunately, this is easy because queries compose:

```
var query = people.Where(n.surname == "surname" || n.forename == "forename");
if (dropdown.SelectedIndex > 0)
{
    query = query.Where(n => n.id.ToString() == dropdown.SelectedValue);
}
```

Comment: Looks like id is an integer, but the SelectedValue property is a string.  One or the other will need to be converted.

Comment: getting an error "cannot be inferred from usage error in my the if statement query = query??

Comment: I needed paramater in the where
query = query.Where(n => n.id == dropdown.SelectedValue);
Thanks guys

Comment: Don't you love this feature? It's like dynamic SQL but with less evil :)

Comment: (Fixed both errors in the answer. Love to know what the downvote is for.)

Comment: +1 Jon for stating "*queries compose*" because that made the light come on and make these problems easier to solve when thinking like that.